# Is Incense duration level-based?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am level 6 trainer, and I have had 3 incense. I've used 2 already, and the description mentions 30 minute duration. However, both my incense lasted only 20 minutes, and the time bar(circle?) looked like 1/3 of it was missing.

Is this because of my low level, or a bug? If a bug, is there a way to get my 20 minutes of incense back?

Comment: Could it be that your device time was 10 minutes off? Changing your device clock seems to directly affect the indicator it seems

Comment: @IvoBeckers it might be. So if I change the clock to be 20 minutes off in the other way, I get 50 minutes incense?

Comment: Incense always lasts for 30 minutes (barring a server glitch), so if your client's time is off, the effects will still occur (pokemon will spawn) even if the animation doesn't show up.

Answer (score 3):

Incense always lasts 30 minutes. What might be throwing you off is the fact that it lasts 30 minutes of real time (regardless of whether or not you have the app open). So, if you activate the incense at 1:00, it will go away at 1:30. It's also possible that a server glitch or inaccurate time on your phone caused it to last shorter than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then I changed the time on my phone and now I get 30 min incense.